# Error using NSMutableArray of double

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have this function:

```
- (NSMutableArray) getXYbyLLA: (metaio::LLACoordinate) lla
{
NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];        

double latitude = lla.latitude;
double longitude = lla.longitude;

int mapWidth    = 200;
int mapHeight   = 100;

double partialCalc = 0.5555555555555556;                                  


double x = (longitude+180)*partialCalc;                                   

[res addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:x]];                            


double latRad = latitude * M_PI/180;


double mercN = log(tan((M_PI / 4)+(latRad/2)));
double y = (mapHeight/2)-(mapWidth*mercN/(2 * M_PI));

[res addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:y]];                            

return res;


}
```

But I get this error on return:

> Cannot initialize return object of type NSMutableArray with an lvalue of type NSMutableArray

Comment: Note that using the literal syntax for `NSNumbers` can make code more readable: `[res addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:x]];` to `[res addObject:@(x)];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to put `*` in the method signature. You are returning an `NSMutableArray *` but in the method signature you write `NSMutableArray` only.

Instead of:

```
- (NSMutableArray) getXYbyLLA: (metaio::LLACoordinate) lla
```

Use:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getXYbyLLA:(metaio::LLACoordinate)lla
```

Comment: Carefully reading the error messages is a key. But this is a common error, I make it often going between ObjC and Swift.

Comment: @Ravo86: Don't say sorry. It's a common mistake. But you should trust the compiler first before anyone else :) and check those error messages and warning symbols. It'll help you to find the issue. Happy Coding !!!